# android webview set font size system default?

Tags: android, fonts, webview, font-size, text-size

i have `webview` loaded with custom htlm string

my problem is when i set my phone text size as largest the `webview` text still as normal or small

i found `solution` to set `webview` text size but its fixed

is there any way to make `webview` `text` `size` as system default text size ?

this is my webview setting

```
holder.message.getSettings().setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work:

```java
        WebView webview = result.findViewById(R.id.webview);

        WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
        float scale = 100f*getResources().getConfiguration().fontScale;
        settings.setTextZoom((int)scale);

        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/file.html");
```

It gets the scale from the system configuration, then uses that to set the zoom factor.
In my HTML I added < font size="4" > to make it just a little bigger.

Comment: Works like a charm, and the best thing is that it does not create problems on the Android versions where the webview is "smart" (probably Lollipop+) and presets the textZoom the same way.