How to integrate a React Ionic Web Application inside Unity?
Im integrating a Unity-based mobile game with a web-based mobile application built using Ionic + Capacitor and React.
Used plugin: https://github.com/gree/unity-webview
The goal is to embed the web-based mobile app inside the Unity mobile game, allowing users to interact with the web app’s functionality while be inside the mobile game.
WebView is working when loading external URLs (e.g., Google).
Now moving on with the main goal: we’ve copied the web app's compiled files (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.) into Unity’s StreamingAssets folder.
We need to properly load the local index.html file of the web app in the WebView, and ensure that it can also load all the necessary local resources (like JS, CSS, and assets) from the StreamingAssets folder without issues.
In short, the problem is serving local files from Unity’s StreamingAssets folder inside a WebView for Android/iOS platforms.

I  need help to fix the WebViewHandler.cs script to serve the problem is serving local files from Unity’s StreamingAssets and not a simple external URL.

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
#if UNITY_2018_4_OR_NEWER
using UnityEngine.Networking;
#endif
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SampleWebView : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject webViewGameObject;  // The GameObject holding the WebView component


    public string Url;
    public Text status;
    WebViewObject webViewObject;
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        webViewObject = (new GameObject("WebViewObject")).AddComponent<WebViewObject>();
#if UNITY_EDITOR_OSX || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
        webViewObject.canvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas");
#endif
        webViewObject.Init(
            cb: (msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("CallFromJS[{0}]", msg));
                status.text = msg;
                status.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
            },
            err: (msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("CallOnError[{0}]", msg));
                status.text = msg;
                status.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
            },
            httpErr: (msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("CallOnHttpError[{0}]", msg));
                status.text = msg;
                status.GetComponent<Animation>().Play();
            },
            started: (msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("CallOnStarted[{0}]", msg));
            },
            hooked: (msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("CallOnHooked[{0}]", msg));
            },
            cookies: (msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("CallOnCookies[{0}]", msg));
            },
            ld: (msg) =>
            {
                Debug.Log(string.Format("CallOnLoaded[{0}]", msg));
#if UNITY_EDITOR_OSX || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX || UNITY_IOS
                // NOTE: the following js definition is required only for UIWebView; if
                // enabledWKWebView is true and runtime has WKWebView, Unity.call is defined
                // directly by the native plugin.
#if true
                var js = @"
                    if (!(window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers)) {
                        window.Unity = {
                            call: function(msg) {
                                window.location = 'unity:' + msg;
                            }
                        };
                    }
                ";
#else
                // NOTE: depending on the situation, you might prefer this 'iframe' approach.
                // cf. https://github.com/gree/unity-webview/issues/189
                var js = @"
                    if (!(window.webkit && window.webkit.messageHandlers)) {
                        window.Unity = {
                            call: function(msg) {
                                var iframe = document.createElement('IFRAME');
                                iframe.setAttribute('src', 'unity:' + msg);
                                document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);
                                iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);
                                iframe = null;
                            }
                        };
                    }
                ";
#endif
#elif UNITY_WEBPLAYER || UNITY_WEBGL
                var js = @"
                    window.Unity = {
                        call:function(msg) {
                            parent.unityWebView.sendMessage('WebViewObject', msg);
                        }
                    };
                ";
#else
                var js = "";
#endif
                webViewObject.EvaluateJS(js + @"Unity.call('ua=' + navigator.userAgent)");
            }
            //transparent: false,
            //zoom: true,
            //ua: "custom user agent string",
            //radius: 0,  // rounded corner radius in pixel
            //// android
            //androidForceDarkMode: 0,  // 0: follow system setting, 1: force dark off, 2: force dark on
            //// ios
            //enableWKWebView: true,
            //wkContentMode: 0,  // 0: recommended, 1: mobile, 2: desktop
            //wkAllowsLinkPreview: true,
            //// editor
            //separated: false
            );

        // cf. https://github.com/gree/unity-webview/issues/1094#issuecomment-2358718029
        while (!webViewObject.IsInitialized())
        {
            yield return null;
        }

#if UNITY_EDITOR_OSX || UNITY_STANDALONE_OSX
        webViewObject.bitmapRefreshCycle = 1;
        webViewObject.devicePixelRatio = 1;  // 1 or 2
#endif
        // cf. https://github.com/gree/unity-webview/pull/512
        // Added alertDialogEnabled flag to enable/disable alert/confirm/prompt dialogs. by KojiNakamaru · Pull Request #512 · gree/unity-webview
        //webViewObject.SetAlertDialogEnabled(false);

        // cf. https://github.com/gree/unity-webview/pull/728
        //webViewObject.SetCameraAccess(true);
        //webViewObject.SetMicrophoneAccess(true);

        // cf. https://github.com/gree/unity-webview/pull/550
        // introduced SetURLPattern(..., hookPattern). by KojiNakamaru · Pull Request #550 · gree/unity-webview
        //webViewObject.SetURLPattern("", "^https://.*youtube.com", "^https://.*google.com");

        // cf. https://github.com/gree/unity-webview/pull/570
        // Add BASIC authentication feature (Android and iOS with WKWebView only) by takeh1k0 · Pull Request #570 · gree/unity-webview
        //webViewObject.SetBasicAuthInfo("id", "password");

        //webViewObject.SetScrollbarsVisibility(true);

        webViewObject.SetMargins(5, 100, 5, Screen.height / 4);
        webViewObject.SetTextZoom(100);  // android only. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647641/android-webview-set-font-size-system-default/47017410#47017410
        //webViewObject.SetMixedContentMode(2);  // android only. 0: MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW, 1: MIXED_CONTENT_NEVER_ALLOW, 2: MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE
        webViewObject.SetVisibility(true);

#if !UNITY_WEBPLAYER && !UNITY_WEBGL
        if (Url.StartsWith("http"))
        {
            webViewObject.LoadURL(Url.Replace(" ", "%20"));
        }
        else
        {
            var exts = new string[]{
                ".jpg",
                ".js",
                ".html"  // should be last
            };
            foreach (var ext in exts)
            {
                var url = Url.Replace(".html", ext);
                var src = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, url);
                var dst = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.temporaryCachePath, url);
                byte[] result = null;
                if (src.Contains("://"))
                {  // for Android
#if UNITY_2018_4_OR_NEWER
                    // NOTE: a more complete code that utilizes UnityWebRequest can be found in https://github.com/gree/unity-webview/commit/2a07e82f760a8495aa3a77a23453f384869caba7#diff-4379160fa4c2a287f414c07eb10ee36d
                    var unityWebRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(src);
                    yield return unityWebRequest.SendWebRequest();
                    result = unityWebRequest.downloadHandler.data;
#else
                    var www = new WWW(src);
                    yield return www;
                    result = www.bytes;
#endif
                }
                else
                {
                    result = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(src);
                }
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(dst, result);
                if (ext == ".html")
                {
                    webViewObject.LoadURL("file://" + dst.Replace(" ", "%20"));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
#else
        if (Url.StartsWith("http")) {
            webViewObject.LoadURL(Url.Replace(" ", "%20"));
        } else {
            webViewObject.LoadURL("StreamingAssets/" + Url.Replace(" ", "%20"));
        }
#endif
        yield break;
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        var x = 10;

        GUI.enabled = (webViewObject == null) ? false : webViewObject.CanGoBack();
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, 10, 80, 80), "<"))
        {
            webViewObject?.GoBack();
        }
        GUI.enabled = true;
        x += 90;

        GUI.enabled = (webViewObject == null) ? false : webViewObject.CanGoForward();
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, 10, 80, 80), ">"))
        {
            webViewObject?.GoForward();
        }
        GUI.enabled = true;
        x += 90;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, 10, 80, 80), "r"))
        {
            webViewObject?.Reload();
        }
        x += 90;

        GUI.TextField(new Rect(x, 10, 180, 80), "" + ((webViewObject == null) ? 0 : webViewObject.Progress()));
        x += 190;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, 10, 80, 80), "*"))
        {
            var g = GameObject.Find("WebViewObject");
            if (g != null)
            {
                Destroy(g);
            }
            else
            {
                StartCoroutine(Start());
            }
        }
        x += 90;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, 10, 80, 80), "c"))
        {
            webViewObject?.GetCookies(Url);
        }
        x += 90;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, 10, 80, 80), "x"))
        {
            webViewObject?.ClearCookies();
        }
        x += 90;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, 10, 80, 80), "D"))
        {
            webViewObject?.SetInteractionEnabled(false);
        }
        x += 90;

        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(x, 10, 80, 80), "E"))
        {
            webViewObject?.SetInteractionEnabled(true);
        }
        x += 90;
    }
}



Be problem specific, please! You can use the web view to open any url.

@MuhammadAfzaal Hi, thanks for replying; I edited the questions with more details, check it

Working perfect for me. With 2020.3.46 build is tested on android. This web view is not for editor make sure the testing platform. Do share the error or exception you are facing.

Have you tried loading a complex react application with webview? I have passed the content of the build inside the StreamingAssets folder, and pointing at the index.html, but I cannot see the react webapp inside the unity game, just a blank white page covering the unity menu game

Have you make the build of react app ?
